# How to use already set ItemSource in style

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, binding

my Question is how can I reference a `ItemsSource` I have already set on my `Window` inside a `Style`? I have the following `ListViews`:

**AppointmentOverview.xaml**

```
    <ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Mov}"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Mon}"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Div}"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Din}"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Miv}"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Min}"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Dov}"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Don}"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Frv}"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Frn}"/>
```

As you can see every `ListView` has a different `ItemsSource` so I can't set the `ItemsSource` via the `Style`. But they all have the same `Style`. This `Style` should contain a `Composite Collection`. The `Composite Collection` should contain this `ItemsSource` + one `Button`. My Question is how can tell the `CollectionViewSource` that it should use the already set `ItemsSource`? My `Styles` are in a different File.

**Styles.xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="5" Columns="1"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>        
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Border BorderBrush="#5076A7" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#C0D3EA" Offset="1.0"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                    <StackPanel TextElement.FontFamily="Segoe UI" TextElement.FontSize="12">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Padding="3,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Betreff}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <Button FontSize="7" Content="X" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                                    Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteButtonCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding ItemId}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <TextBlock Padding="3,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Kunde}"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Padding="3,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Ort}"/>
                            <TextBlock Padding="3,0,0,0" Text="("/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Alternative}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text=")"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Betreff}" Value="Blocked">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource BlockedListViewItem}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Probably you can creatte an attached property and use it in style instead of the ItemsSource.

Comment: Could you post an example? I'm having trouble creating an Attatched Property for IEnumerable.

Comment: Could you please add your existing list view Style to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Attached Property that will keep the initial collection to avoid conflicts with the collection that will be injected in the style. You will have to create a new DependencyObject class or define it in an existing one:

```
public class Extensions : DependencyObject
{

    #region MyItemsSource

    /// <summary>
    /// MyItemsSource Attached Dependency Property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(Extensions),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((IEnumerable)null));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the MyItemsSource property. This dependency property 
    /// indicates ....
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerable GetMyItemsSource(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (IEnumerable)d.GetValue(MyItemsSourceProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the MyItemsSource property. This dependency property 
    /// indicates ....
    /// </summary>
    public static void SetMyItemsSource(DependencyObject d, IEnumerable value)
    {
        d.SetValue(MyItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }

    #endregion


}
```

Now in XAML the ListView will look like this:

```
<ListView  local:Extensions.MyItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Style="{StaticResource ListBox_Style}"/>
```

To actually bind the ItemsSource to the MyItemsSource property inside a CompositeCollection there is no simple solution. A compositeCollection is not a Visual object and not even a DependencyProperty so no findAncestor bindings are possible. And using CollectionViewSource as a resource of the style won't work in this case.

Some workaround is needed here. One possibility is to use a Converter:

```
public class CollectionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public ControlTemplate AdditionalControlTemplate { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        CompositeCollection cc = new CompositeCollection();

        //Add base ItemSource
        CollectionContainer cont = new CollectionContainer();
        cont.Collection = (IEnumerable)value;
        cc.Add(cont);

        //Add a control at the end
        if(AdditionalControlTemplate != null)
            cc.Add(new Control() { Template = AdditionalControlTemplate });

        return cc;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This converter takes the source collection and injects it into a CompositeCollection. Then a control is added to this collection with a template that can be specified outside of the converter. So your button can go inside of this ControlTemplate. The ListView style will then look like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ListBox_Style" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <!-- Control template for the object to be added at the end of the ListView -->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="AdditionalButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
            <Button Content="Hello World!"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <local:CollectionConverter x:Key="CollectionConverter" AdditionalControlTemplate="{StaticResource AdditionalButtonTemplate}"/>
    </Style.Resources>

    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding (local:Extensions.MyItemsSource), Converter={StaticResource CollectionConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</Style>
```

A simpler sollution to bypass CompositeCollection restrictions would be to use an intermediate  ItemsControl. So instead of ListView you will use an ItemsControl:

With the following style:

```
<Style x:Key="icListViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
                <ListView>
                    <ListView.Resources>
                        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="BaseItemsSource" Source="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}, AncestorLevel=2}}"/>
                    </ListView.Resources>
                    <ListView.ItemsSource>
                        <CompositeCollection>
                            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource BaseItemsSource}}"/>
                            <Button Content="Hello World!"/>
                        </CompositeCollection>
                    </ListView.ItemsSource>
                </ListView>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here BaseItemsSource is a resource of ListView which is an actual visual object and so the RelativeSource can be resolved in the binding.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. At the Moment I have to work on another Project but if I have time I will test your answer.

Comment: I have tried it but sadly it doesn't work. Nothing is displayed but I also don't get any Errors. In the Output window I get the following Message `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Kunde' property not found on 'object' ''Control' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Kunde; DataItem='Control' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')` Also do I use the two last style or just one of them?